# How to insert a SIM card on a MyWigo City?

Tags: hardware, sim-card, dual-sim

First of all, excuse me if this is not the correct site to ask this question or if it seems too stupid, but I have been struggling with that for some hours and I couldn't solve it yet.

The point is that I want to insert a SIM card to a MyWigo City (http://www.mywigo.com/smartphones-mywigo/mywigo-city.html) but I don't know how to do it. It's a dual-SIM phone, but I can only see one slot for SIM cards. In the pictogram next to it, it says that I have to insert the SIM cards horizontally and one overlapping the other? It doesn't make any sense for me.

[image: MyWigo City SIM card slot]

I tried all possible ways I could imagine and none of them worked.

Comment: That's really confusing.  From the drawing, the bottom card (#2) should be upside-down.  Is there a way to insert it under one set of contacts while exposing the others for #1?

Comment: I agree that this is exceptionally confusing, as the indications end up with the contacts face-to-face. That said, looking at their other phones, one interesting and important clue is that the size differences are valid. It takes one micro-SIM and one mini-SIM (what people consider a "standard" SIM, which is the larger one). It's possible that that's part of what's tripping you up. I'd take a bet that counter to the photo, the micro goes on the bottom, face-down, and the mini on top, face-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I had to contact the company to figure out how it works. The pictogram shows 1. a micro-SIM (on top) and 2. a standard SIM (below). I didn't notice the first time but below the slot for the micro-SIM, there is a small space where the standard SIM is supposed to go.